# I can't modify excel data I read from python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am currently trying to develop a program, to use it I need to read data from an excel with Pandas.
The problem is that once I open Anaconda and Jupiter and run the program it won't let me go back to modify the excel it gets data from.
The program works and reads initial data, but I can't modify the excel sheet and save it for the program to run with other input data.

```
excel=pd.ExcelFile(r'C:\Users\ADURAN3\Anaconda3\python.xlsx')

df=pd.read_excel(excel,'Sheet1',index_col=0)
```

When I try to save the excel sheet with the new changes it forces me to rename it.

I would love it if you could help me, I am very new to pyhton.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried closing the file with `excel.close()` before writing to it?

Answer (score 0):

To read an excel file, you don't need to do `pd.ExcelFile(r'C:\Users\ADURAN3\Anaconda3\python.xlsx')`

Just putting your file path into read_excel will work:

`df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\ADURAN3\Anaconda3\python.xlsx','Sheet1',index_col=0)`